# using git to maintain old versions

Tags: git

I’ve been reading up on git branching workflows and there seems to be an assumption that branches are there for development purposes with everything eventually being merged back into master. I can’t find much discussion about using long-running branches for maintenance of older versions.

For example, here’s how my workflow works in SVN (based around the perforce “tofu” model). Let’s say the latest released version is 4.1 but I’m also supporting versions 4.0, 3.5, and 3.6, so there is a maintenance branch for each of these. Trunk is used for features that won’t be released until 4.2. Now say a customer needs a bug fix to version 3.6. I’ll make the fix into my 3.6 maintenance branch and make a new maintenance release (for the sake of argument, 3.6.22).

At this point the fix is merged downwards into 4.0 and from there to 4.1, 4.2, and trunk, and from there, into any development branches made from trunk. Note that this is not a cherry-pick merge; it’s a normal SVN automatic merge.

If the fix is non-trivial we might make a dev branch from the 3.6 release branch and then reintegrate it in the normal way before releasing. Similarly, If the merge-down to 4.1 is non-trivial, we might make a development branch from 4.1 to merge into and then reintegrate it back up into 4.1 release when we’re happy with the merge.

When we release version 4.2 we will branch off a maintenance branch for that in the same way, and trunk will become ongoing 4.3 work

Should I (or even can I) use exactly the same workflow in git, or is this “old-hat” traditional svn thinking which needs to be reconsidered?

Comment: You actually have no other options than maintening at least 1 branch per released codeline. I work as you describe here on both perforce and git (well the integration team sometimes make it a little bit more complex xD)

Comment: You may use git `tag` (lightweight) and then if you require any fix on a specific version you can create a new branch using the tag or else it will be as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Branching strategies do not really change much depending on the version control technology.  What you described sounds like pretty standard branching workflow for a live product.  What would change in moving to Git from another tool like SVN is the *cost* of creating and maintaining a branch.  In Git, branching is extremely cheap.  A branch in Git is basically just a pointer to a commit.  So the cost, for example, of creating a maintenance branch containing only a few commits would be incrementally very small.  This might not be the case with a tool like SVN, where a copy or every file in the project might need to be created.